# Prevent access to route with "/Index"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

In .NET MVC routing, is there a way for me to prevent access to the Index action when explicitly typing it, i.e. I want it to return a 404 as if the action wasn't valid?

I want to achieve:

> www.example.com **/Index** => 404 error code
>
> **www.example.com** => "Root", should run the **Index** action on the default controller.

Like similar on StackOverflow, `/Index` gives me 404, that's what I want to simulate as well.

Right now, both `/` and `/Index` gives me a valid page - the start page.

The default route right now:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: Remove the route that matches that URL.

Comment: @SLaks How should I rewrite the default route?

Comment: I just fired up a new MVC project, went to /Index and I got a 404... What have you chcanged? Did you goto: /Home/Index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by altering the URL of the default route (Root) to be empty.

> **In ASP.NET Core 1.1.1**:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("Home_Root", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `/Home/Index` and not `/Index`, you just need to add `IgnoreRoute` to your configuration.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("Home/Index");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Home");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```